# Explain the difference in scan + posting to participating source in RxJava vs Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, kotlin-coroutines

I am porting a piece of code from Rx to Coroutines and came across the behavior I can't wrap my head around.

> Background: imagine that you have a stream of values each one gets associated with an action-lambda to be executed later. There's also an "external" stream to which lambda can post and it's merged in the resulting stream.

I reduced the original code to this simpler (but still tricky) version:

```kotlin
val shared = PublishSubject.create<String>()
Observable
  .merge(
    subject.map { it to { } },
    Observable.just("item1", "item2")
      .map { it to { shared.onNext(it.toUpperCase()) } }
  )
  .scan("*" to { }) { accumulator, value ->
    (accumulator.first + "_" + value.first) to value.second
  }
  .subscribe {
    it.second()
    println("got ${it.first}")
  }
```

This prints

```
got *
got *_item1
got *_item1_ITEM1
got *_item1_ITEM1_item2
got *_item1_ITEM1_item2_ITEM2
```

Next I have this coroutines + flow based version.
The notable difference is that it has `suspend` modifier added to the lambda (to be able to call `shared.emit()`.

```kotlin
runBlocking {
  val shared = MutableSharedFlow<String>()
  merge(
    shared.map { it to suspend {} },
    flowOf("item1", "item2").map { it to suspend { shared.emit(it.toUpperCase()) } }
  )
    .scan("*" to suspend { }) { accumulator, value ->
      (accumulator.first + "_" + value.first) to value.second
    }
    .collect {
      it.second()
      println("got ${it.first}")
    }
}
```

This prints

```
got *
got *_item1
got *_item1_item2
got *_item1_item1_ITEM1
got *_item1_item2_ITEM1_ITEM2
```

Notice, that in the Rx version uppercased ITEM emissions were interspersed with lowercase ones, while in the coroutines version they come last.

Questions I'd like to ask:

1. Why does this happen? Is it due to the suspending lambda? Would be grateful for step-by-step explanation if there is something complex going on
2. Does Rx have some internal buffer which allows it to behave as it does?
3. Can similar behavior be achieved with Flow and if so, how?

Comment: I see two differences: the RxJava version runs synchronously thus "item1" does trigger the paired function before "item2" is emitted. Second, RxJava's `merge` implementation is a bit eager and checks all inputs for more items, thus when "item1" uppercase gets signaled via the subject, `merge` will see it and forward it before allowing just to continue with "item2". I don't know what Flow does, probably has buffers or flowOf.map has a shortcut in merge thus merge emits all of flowOf before considering the sharedflow input.

Comment: @akarnokd thank you! that makes it clearer. I've also noticed that if I move that lambda out of "just.map" and instead create it right inside the scan's body i.e.."item to { onNext() }", then both versions start to behave identically. So maybe that eagerness of "merge" really comes into play here!

Comment: I think `merge` in Kotlin [has a buffer](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/b7e08b8f4aac30227e30d7101600443de86d9832/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/flow/operators/Merge.kt#L105). But ultimately I think it's bad code to depend on such sequencing behaviour.

Comment: @GeorgeLeung yeah, agreed. Just was curious to untangle what happens here.